# How do I update a variable logged in to Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log, google-chrome-console

Let say I need to track the window size and log the output. I add an event listner and use

```
console.log(window.innerWidth)
```

However this adds a new line to the console every time the window is resized.

What I need is to show the innerWidth in a single line in the console which updates it everytime the window is resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Garbee said, you can't achieve that functionality in the standard Console. You could alternatively use a watch variable to keep track of `window.innerWidth`. Unfortunately you need to manually reload it.

[image: using watch variable to keep track of window.innerWidth]

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a line that updates. The console lines are appended to, not capable of being overwritten.

You need to build a custom UX to handle this need for your app as an overlay. Or you can use Device Mode as "Responsive" to let you resize freely and see the update width/height within that window.